# Python. Data structure for storing objects coordinates on map

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph-algorithm, game-development

I'm developing the game server. I want data structure for storing 3d-coordinates (x, y, z) of the objects on the map. This objects can dynamically change their position (move, teleport, be destroyed etc). I want to store this coordinates in specific order according to their visual position on the map. So, I think using graph for this purpose is good choice. But I'm not sure.

Please, notice, I need to store real-time coordinates for many objects (about 4-5 thousands). Does it exists library or algorithm to implement what I need ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I need search the nearest objects by coordinates, need to find the place where to insert the new object (or replace old) according to their coordinates. Mm I will look into Octree, it seems it is good variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a spatial structure like an [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) (for 3D spaces) or [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (for 2D spaces).

They partition their contents into buckets that group neighboring coordinates together. This makes doing checks surrounding a coordinate quick because only one bucket of coords (or, only buckets immediately surrounding the coord's bucket for larger checks) need to be checked. This can greatly limit the number of objects that need to be checked.

These structures arr commonly used for collision detection in games.